# showing syntax error when trying to run in pycharm

Tags: django, python-2.7, pycharm

When i try to run a project it is showing the following message :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 3.4.1\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Python27\python.exe G:/project/sample3/manage.py runserver 8000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/project/sample3/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 238, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 41, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\runserver.py", line 18
    def get_handler(self, *args, use_static_handler=True, insecure_serving=False, **options):
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

this happens to all the projects . this problem started unexpectedly...

Comment: What version of Python 2.7 do you have installed?

Comment: python 2.7.8  but pycharm worked fine at the first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may have accidentally modified the Django code in your installation, because this is not what [line 18 of this file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/runserver.py#L18) looks  like in the actual Django source code. Please try to uninstall and reinstall Django.

Comment: Ok later i reinstalled pycharm, but now i renstalled django and now it works fine.. Thank u all....